# can't get extremely basic metalsmith installation to build pages

Tags: node.js, metalsmith

Metalsmith portrays itself as a ridiculously simple static site generator. I'm trying to write the most basic of sites just to get myself familiar with the basics of the software, but I can't seem to get even that to build. Here's my folder structure:

```
|- build/
|- index.js
|- src/
    |-index.html
|- templates
    |-index.hbt
```

My `index.js` file:

```
var Metalsmith = require('metalsmith');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .destination('./build')
    .build();
```

My `index.html` file:

```
---
title: Home
template: index.hbt
---
```

And my `index.hbt` template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FOO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        something
    </body>
</html>
```

My understanding is that the `build` command should look through the `src` directory and parse any file it finds with that YAML stuff at the top. So it should look at `index.html`, see that it renders using the `templates/index.hbt` template, and basically just move the file into `build/index.html`. But when I run `node index.js` I get absolutely nothing. No progress indicator, no "Done building your stuff!" message, just a blinking command prompt line. My build directory is empty. Obviously something is breaking, but there are no logs to check, and no status messages to google. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't there be at least one page created in the `build` directory?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, in a comment on a tutorial, of all places: https://blog.robinthrift.com/2014/04/14/metalsmith-part-1-setting-up-the-forge/. It's also on the github examples: https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith

According to those links, you need to include an error callback on the `.build()` function:

```
Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .build(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Comment: I personally do more ... I output errors to a build log. This way I can see them later.

Comment: That's a good idea, @JamesKhoury. I'll have to implement that. Thanks!

Comment: If you do could you share it with us? I would love to see how you do it in comparison.

Comment: Looks like he changed his mod_rewrite rules. Updated with the new link, though the comments are no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the error callback issue, which you've already identified, I think you're missing a few things in your files. True, Metalsmith is very simple, but its simplicity means that a lot of the functionality (like support for templates) is brought by modules that you need to install and include explicitly.

You say the content of your `index.js` file is:

```
var Metalsmith = require('metalsmith');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .destination('./build')
    .build();
```

Is that everything you have in you `index.js`? If you want to use Handlebars templates, you need to explicitly add the [metalsmith plugin that handles templates](https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith-templates#metalsmith-templates), and instruct it to use handlebars:

```
var Metalsmith = require('metalsmith');
var templates = require('metalsmith-templates');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .destination('./build')
    .use(templates('handlebars'))
    .build();
```

And make sure that you install the `metalsmith-templates` and `handlebars` modules from npm.

Also, you probably know this, but in your `index.hbt`, you'll need to change

```
    <title>FOO</title>
```

to

```
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
```

in order to load the title metadata from `index.html`.

Let me know if this gets you going, or if you need more help.

Comment: btw, the `metalsmith-template` plugin has been deprecated, and split in to 2 different plugins `metalsmith-layout` and `metalsmith-in-place`